# How to read input from a file in a java project using netbeans 7.2 on fedora?

Tags: java, netbeans, fedora, file-io, netbeans-7.2

the file is aa.txt in the directory `/home/user`
the code I wrote is

```
input=new FileInputStream("//home//user//aa.txt");
```

but the program can not open the file. when I run it on windows, it works
what is the format of the path in fedora to be read correctly by the program???

Comment: solved using the forward slash /home/user/aa.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\` is used as an escape character (for instance `\n` = new line and `\t` = tab) we need to write `\\` to mean a single `\` when placing this character in a String.

This issue does not exist with a forward slash `/` 
For linux directories the forward slash `/` is used; windows uses the backslash. Writing OS independent code could be a pain, but it's not an issue. Just use the forward slash when dealing with files and Java automagically translates it for you to the correct OS specific format.

For instance `C:/Users/Owner/Documents` becomes `C:\Users\Owner\Documents` on windows.
Or you could write `"C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents"` but the simple forward slash format looks simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape the `/` (slash) character.

So you basically need this:

```
input=new FileInputStream("/home/user/aa.txt");
```

However, it is far wiser to use [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) instead:

```
input=new FileInputStream(File.separator+"home"+File.separator+"user"+File.separator+"aa.txt");
```